# How to get value of a Keras tensor in TensorFlow 2?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

TF1 had `sess.run()` and `.eval()` to get values of tensors - and Keras had `K.get_value()`; now, neither work the same (former two at all).

`K.eager(K.get_value)(tensor)` appears to work inside Keras graph by exiting it, and `K.get_value(tensor)` outside the graph - both w/ TF2's default eagerly (which is *off* in former). However, this fails if `tensor` is a *Keras backend operation*:

```py
import keras.backend as K
def tensor_info(x):
    print(x)
    print("Type: %s" % type(x))
    try:        
        x_value = K.get_value(x)
    except:
        try:    x_value = K.eager(K.get_value)(x)
        except: x_value = x.numpy()
    print("Value: %s" % x_value)  # three methods

ones = K.ones(1)
ones_sqrt = K.sqrt(ones)

tensor_info(ones); print()
tensor_info(ones_sqrt)
```

```py
<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([1.], dtype=float32)>
Type: <class 'tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops.ResourceVariable'>
Value: [1.]

Tensor("Sqrt:0", shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
Type: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
# third print fails w/ below
```

```py
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

---

This is a non-issue in TF < 2.0. [Github](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/13396)'s been silent. I'm aware of ways to rewrite the code as a workaround, but it'll eliminate Keras' backend-neutrality and work akin to `tf.keras`. Is there a way to get Keras 2.3 tensor values in TensorFlow 2.0 while retaining backend-neutrality?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you want [`K.eval`](https://keras.io/backend#eval):

```
>>> v = K.ones(1)
>>> K.eval(v)
array([1.], dtype=float32)
>>> K.eval(K.sqrt(v))
array([1.], dtype=float32)
```

Note that [`K.get_value`](https://keras.io/backend/#get_value) is reserved for use with variables (e.g. `v` here) while `K.eval` works with any tensor.

Comment: Thank you; however, only works with `import keras.backend as K` - fails for `tensorflow.keras.backend` and `tensorflow.python.keras.backend`. As other functionality may depend on latter two, this isn't a complete answer. It may, however, be a bug - can you confirm?

Comment: I've checked the snippet with the imports you've listed, and all three produce the same result. Could you update your question with the outputs you get in each of these cases?

Comment: All's good - turns out `tf.python` isn't meant to be used anyway (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58279628/what-is-the-difference-between-tf-keras-and-tf-python-keras)), or not always.

Answer (score 1):

Per my [PR](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/33318), this is the more reliable (but not guaranteed) workaround:

```py
def K_eval(x):
    try:
        return K.get_value(K.to_dense(x))
    except:
        eval_fn = K.function([], [x])
        return eval_fn([])[0]
```

---

**Update**: mind the *distrubution context* under which a `Tensor` is to be evaluated; in TF2.2, a `tf.Variable` or `tf.Tensor` created under `tf.python.distribute.distribution_strategy_context.in_replica_context() == True` will fail any `K.eval`-etc attempts. Looks like tensors simply aren't meant to be evaluated there.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is `tf.keras.backend.get_value` API.

```
print(x)
>>tf.Tensor([1.], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
print(tf.keras.backend.get_value(x))
>>[1.]
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case tensorflow 2.0 this works when printing the loss:

```
 import tensorflow as tf
 from tensorflow import keras
```

...

```
  print(loss_value)
  print(float(loss_value) )
```

output:

```
    tf.Tensor(2.3782592, shape=(), dtype=float32)
    2.3782591819763184
```