# What is the difference between tf.keras and tf.python.keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I've ran into serious incompatibility problems for the same code ran with one vs. the other; e.g.:

- [Getting value of tensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58261348/valueerror-tried-to-convert-y-to-a-tensor-and-failed-error-none-values-not)
- [Compiling model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58261348/valueerror-tried-to-convert-y-to-a-tensor-and-failed-error-none-values-not)
- [Saving optimizer](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33100)

Looking into the [Github source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.0/tensorflow/python/keras/__init__.py), the modules and their imports look fairly identical, and `tf.keras` even imports from `tf.python.keras`. In tutorials, I see both being used time to time. As an example, code below will fail with `tf.python.keras`.

What's the deal? What is the difference, and when should I use one or the other?

---

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Nadam
import numpy as np

ipt   = Input(shape=(4,))
out   = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(ipt)
model = Model(ipt, out)
model.compile(optimizer=Nadam(lr=1e-4), loss='binary_crossentropy')

X = np.random.randn(32,4)
Y = np.random.randint(0,2,(32,1))
model.train_on_batch(X,Y)
```

---

**ADDITIONAL INFO**:

- CUDA 10.0.130, cuDNN 7.4.2, Python 3.7.4, Windows 10
- `tensorflow`, `tensorflow-gpu` v2.0.0, and Keras 2.3.0 via pip, all else via Anaconda 3

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From an official [TensorFlow dev](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33075#issuecomment-539070546), shortened (emphasis mine):

> The API import is in the root of the package. Any other import is just Python allowing you to access privates with no consideration for good coding practices.
>
> The only way that imports should be are
>
> ```py
> import tensorflow as tf
> tf.keras
> ```
>
> We also provide support for `from tensorflow.keras import`,
>   though this is brittle and can break as we keep refactoring.
>   **Importing from `tensorflow.python` or any other modules** (including `import tensorflow_core`) **is not supported, and can break unannounced.**

Me: *To confirm, `tf.python.keras` is **private**, intended for development, rather than **public** use?*

> Yes, that's exactly the case. Anything under `tf.python` is private

---

This, however, is not the full picture. `tf.python` remains the only way to access certain functions / classes - e.g., `tf.python.framework` and `tf.python.ops`, both used in `tf.keras.optimizers`. But as per above, this doesn't become a concern unless you're "developing" - i.e. writing custom functionality or classes. "Out of box" usage should be fine without ever touching `tf.python`.

Note this isn't only a compatibility matter, and the two are *not* interchangeable "as long as nothing breaks"; for example, `tf.keras` uses [optimizer_v2](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py#L79), which differs substantially from `tf.python.keras` [Optimizer](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.0/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizers.py#L47).

Lastly, note that both above links end up in `tf.python.keras` -- not certain, but it appears that `tf.keras` doesn't actually exist in TF Github (e.g. nothing references `OptimizerV2`), but it *does* merge with TF in `tensorflow_core/python/keras/api/_v2` folder when installed locally:

```py
from tensorflow import keras
print(keras.__file__)
from tensorflow.python import keras
print(keras.__file__)
```

```py
D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\api\_v2\keras\__init__.py
D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\__init__.py
```

Though both share the `python/` folder, they're *not* both `tf.python` - can be verified from their respective `__init__.py`.

---

**UPDATE**: `tf.python.keras.optimizers` used with `tf.python.keras.layers` vs `tf.keras.optimizers` used with `tf.keras.layers` runs **11.5x slower** for a mid-sized model ([code](https://pastebin.com/nS1YM1tC)). I continue to see former in user code - consider this a note of warning.

Comment: A lot of time, my environment can't get `tf.keras` properly. Only `tf.python.keras` can be found.

Comment: @LouisYang Depends - as noted, some imports are only found in `tf.python.keras`. If you can't do `from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense` ("out of box"), for example, that's an installation problem.

Comment: Does this only happen for tensorflow 2.0? I am working with Bazel test. Even though I can import from `tf.keras` in a regular python script, the Bazel test cannot see it. Also, my IDE can't see the tf.keras as well. Only the tf.python.keras exists...

Comment: @LouisYang Never used Bazel - I suggest checking its source code to see how it handles imports; some repositories switch to `tf.keras` via an [environment flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58984892/how-to-set-environment-variable-tf-keras-1-for-onnx-conversion/58997783#58997783). Your IDE not finding `tf.keras` but finding `tf.python.keras` is quite strange - may wish to open a question about it.