# Why is K.log value giving me nan in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am writing a custom loss function and I want to take 1 - logarithm of the value calculated. I am writing in keras with tensorflow backend as follows:

```py
nonlabels = list(np.where(predictions<threshold)[1])
loss_fg_nT = 0
probs_nT = tf.gather(probs_fg,nonlabels,axis=3)
for i in range(len(nonlabels)):
    probs_temp = tf.reshape(probs_nT[:,:,:,i],[-1])
    prob_max = tf.math.reduce_max(probs_temp)
    const = tf.constant(0.000001)
    prob_max = tf.math.add(prob_max,const)
    #prob_max = tf.math.subtract(tf.constant(1.0),prob_max)
    val = K.log(prob_max)
    loss_fg_nT -= val
    loss_fg_nT = loss_fg_nT/(len(nonlabels)+0.000001)
```

If i remove `prob_max = tf.math.subtract(tf.constant(1.0),prob_max)` line the function is working fine but when I take log of (1-prob_max) value it is giving `nan` value. I couldn't understand the reason behind this as I am adding a nominal value to avoid taking `log 0` as well. Can someone help me correct this error.

Comment: For which value of `prob_max` does `K.log` yield nans? You can find out via a `try-except` block; also consider using `K.epsilon()` instead of the `0.00..1`, make sure all `reduce_max` outputs are positive, and try `tf.math.log` instead of `K.log`

Comment: it is giving `nan` for every value. I used `K.epsilon()` and also did `tf.math.abs(probs_max)` just to avoid negative values and used `tf.math.log`. But still I am facing the same issue. This is so weird!!

Comment: Yes, it is odd - too odd; possible install issue. Before going there, what is the output of `print(K.get_value(K.log(tf.constant(0.9)))`? Let me know if `nan`, it's a broken install I can suggest steps for. Lastly, where are you importing your `keras.backend` from? Make sure it's consistent with other imports, and that it is **not** [`tf.python.keras`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58279628/what-is-the-difference-between-tf-keras-and-tf-python-keras)

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon, `print(K.get_value(K.log(tf.constant(0.9)))`, this is giving me proper value not `nan`.  I imported keras backend as `keras.backend`.

Comment: I'd find the output of [this script](https://pastebin.com/z8mrS82n) helpful; you can paste it here as pastebin

Answer (score 4):

You are getting nan error because you K.log() for a minus value. Additionally, you get inf error if you K.log() for a zero value. I attach an image to demonstrate that [image: attach_1]

I also attach the code that I used to debug, hope this help you can manually debug in the future
[image: attach_2]

Happy coding!

Comment: But even if I did `tf.math.abs(probs_max)`, I am getting the same error. this ensures that I always have a positive value right? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, using tf.math.abs() makes the value positive, my "attach_2" in last step becames ~13,8023 instead of NaN too, please try to use alternative names for prob_max like I did, I once got error because I keep same name of prob_max, so I change to prob_max_1 , prob_max _2, prob_max _3, and please make sure the dimension of prob_max  is correct (1,) and range from (0-1)

Comment: The value of prob_max is definitely between 0 and 1 as I have used softmax function to get the probabilities. I still have the issue after renaming the variables.

Comment: Could you print out the value of this line prob_max = tf.math.reduce_max(probs_temp)

Comment: You can use tf.Session() as sess, then print(prob_max, feed_dict={probs_temp: probs_temp}), be careful to check there is no other variables named prob_max, it may print the last variables named prob_max instead

Comment: My demo: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13fZE0U3d7csINF27ksCTlBAKICQys6Z6, hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

The input to `K.log()` gets too small. So, prevent `prob_max` from becoming so small:

```
prob_max = K.clip(prob_max, 1e-36, 1e36)
val = K.log(prob_max)
```

My experiment: `1e-36` is fine, but `1e-40` is too small.