# Anaconda installs TensorFlow 1.15 instead of 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I've been trying to install Tensorflow 2.0 in Anaconda.

So far, tensorflow works fine (i can use the library in my code), but when i'm installing it, it says "installing version: 2.0", then i get version 1.15 instead.

The whole package results updatable (since versione 2.0 does exist and should be available), but even if i try to update it, i keep getting 1.15, which gets back to updatable, and i get back into the loop.

I tried both from the Anaconda Navigator interface and the prompt using `conda update tensorflow`, without any success.

Here's there is the link package: [tensorflow 2.0 Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tensorflow)

How can i solve the problem?

**EDIT :**

I successfully installed TensorFlow 2.0 using `conda install -c anaconda tensorflow`. Then i got back into Anaconda Navigator and i tried to install Keras 2.2.4.

Looking at the installed packages, seems that installing Keras overwrites the version 2.0 of TensorFlow with the 1.15, am i wrong? Is this a bug?

Here's the image: [image: Keras install]

Comment: While I am late to the party, would you happen to have the contents of the environment (using something like `conda list`) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu`](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tensorflow-gpu)

*or*

[`conda install -c anaconda tensorflow`](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tensorflow)

Look for these:

[image]

---

**Tip**: completely shred any file w/ name substring "keras" and "tensorflow" in your Anaconda environment before installing - else stuff is likely to break.

1. Navigate to your `site-packages`
2. Search `**keras**` --> delete all results
3. Search `**tensorflow**` --> delete all results

Above should work even better from the environment's root folder (e.g. `envs/tf2_env`) -- the idea is, Anaconda caches whatever it's already installed, so if it isn't completely removed, you may find trouble getting latest vers of packages.

---

**Related Q's answered in comments**:

1. **Why is conda reverting TF 2 to TF 1.15.0 when I try installing Keras 2.2.4?**

   - TF2's only compatible w/ Keras 2.2.5+, so conda is taking care of compatibility
2. **Why are some `from keras` imports no longer working and need `from tensorflow.keras`?**

   - `from keras` is very different from `from tensorflow.keras`, implementation-wise. `from keras` is backend-neutral, whereas `tf.keras` is more tightly integrated w/ TF. There can also be [significant performance differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58441514/why-is-tensorflow-2-much-slower-than-tensorflow-1?noredirect=1&lq=1).  TF2 and onward, `tf.keras` is preferable, and development will proceed along it, as noted by [F. Chollet](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases/tag/2.3.0)
   - Also beware of [`tf.python.keras`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58279628/what-is-the-difference-between-tf-keras-and-tf-python-keras)

Comment: Do i have to install both tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu or one is enough? Is it ok if i remove the already installed packages from the anaconda navigator or i must delete by hand the files (using explorer)?

Comment: @MattiaSurricchio Explorer's the best bet - and only _one_ is enough

Comment: Anyway i updated the question, seems there could be a possible bug in the installation of the packages. Seems that keras overwrites the tensorflow version

Comment: @MattiaSurricchio Not a bug; TF2's only compatible w/ Keras 2.2.5+, so conda is taking care of compatibility here

Comment: Maybe i'm missing something, is Keras now embedded inside the TensorFlow package? I've installed it correctly and it works, but i had to rewrite my import, for example ``from tensorflow.keras import Sequential``, while before i was using just ``from keras import Sequential``. This make me think that now Keras comes with TensorFlow 2.0 and i dont need to install it as a separate package, am i wrong?

Comment: @MattiaSurricchio One'd be surprised, but `from keras` is very different from `from tensorflow.keras`, implementation-wise, and has been since TF1; just run `help(Adam)` for both to see their source path differences. `from keras` is backend-neutral, whereas `tf.keras` is more tightly integrated w/ TF. There can also be [significant performance differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58441514/why-is-tensorflow-2-much-slower-than-tensorflow-1?noredirect=1&lq=1). But yes, TF2 and onward, `tf.keras` is preferable, and development will proceed along it

Answer (score 10):

Another alternative is to install `Tensorflow` with `Miniconda`.

I simply have used `Miniconda3` for windows and I was able to install multiple versions of `Tensorflow` on different environment respectively.

> Example 1

```py
// create a new environment
conda create --name workflowone

// activate environment
conda activate workflowone

// Install desired package
conda install tensorflow=1.15

// deactivate environment
conda deactivate
```

> Example 2

```py
// create a new environment
conda create --name workflowtwo

// activate environment
conda activate workflowtwo

// Install desired package
conda install tensorflow  // If you do not specify the version, you will download the latest version of Tensorflow

// deactivate environment
conda deactivate
```

Comment: for the gpu version, use `conda install tensorflow-gpu=1.15`

Answer (score -1):

In my case, this solved the problem:

```
pip3 install tensorflow==2.0.0a0
```

or even:

```
pip3 install tensorflow --upgrade
```

Comment: I avoided using pip since i read that could lead to some "compatibility" problems if matched with anaconda. Is it possible to "stay" inside the anaconda framework?

Comment: The OP is explicitly asking for a conda solution. Mattia I'd suggest you to don't mix conda and pip in particular if you are going to use env in production. Eventually  you can build a conda package from pip

Answer (score -1):

I struggled with this very problem this week, and found an EASY solution:
Go to Anaconda Navigator (make sure you have the latest update), click on 'Environments' and select 'not installed' from the dropdown menu.  In the search field type "tensorflow".  Click the checkbox for 'tensorflow' but NOT also for 'keras'. Click 'apply' and it will install 2.0, as well as keras.  Then all you have to do to use them is:

import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow import keras

If you had previously installed the unintended versions, delete all of them first, then do the above.

Answer (score -1):

Solved

```
$ conda update --prefix # first step
$ conda 4.8.2  # lates Anaconda
```

> Open Anaconda --> Create environment--> Choose python V3.6
>   --> Search/select TensorFlow 2.0 == Anaconda will upgrade with dependencies

Latest Jupyter in this new environment

```
$ jupyter --version # latest jupyter notebook version created with pyton 3.6
jupyter core     : 4.6.1
jupyter-notebook : 6.0.0
```

[image: Upgrade tf]