# Tensorflow slows intellisense (type-hint) in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, intellisense

im fairly new to TensorFlow but type hints taking forever to popup are kinda getting on my nerves now so I was curious if anybody knew any fixes.

while using TensorFlow 2.0 in vscode jupyter notebook the intellisense dropdown takes up to 2 seconds to actually appear. this only happens when I import TensorFlow, so no other library slows down my IntelliSense.

im on a Mac intel chip for reference. not the fastest machine but still.

- restarting everything
- updating tensorflow

using these two imports seemed to help a bit

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras import Model
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This what i recommend you is to start over with tensorflow with Jupyter notebook with specific virtual environment created on anaconda. Just for that purpose using tensorflow 2.0.

Here is detailed link to instructions:

[Anaconda installs TensorFlow 1.15 instead of 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58944060/anaconda-installs-tensorflow-1-15-instead-of-2-0)

Comment: ive been reading online a bit more and your answer is the general consensus. which sucks cuz I don't really use anaconda.... but hey guess im just ganna use it now :D. thanks!