# Import tensorflow.python.keras instead of tensorflow.keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, visual-studio-code

The autocomplete function of VS Code 1.41.1 does not work for example for

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers
```

(for tensorflow version 1.14.0) but it works for

```
from tensorflow.python.keras import layers
```

So what is the exact difference? Why does it work in the latter case? And is it **always** safe to replace the first method with the second, meaning it produces identical behavior by using the exact same methods?

Comment: So your question is why the autocomplete doesn't work? Not that you're having trouble using `tensorflow.keras.layers` right? And for the difference, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58279628/what-is-the-difference-between-tf-keras-and-tf-python-keras)

Comment: You are right. I am able to use `tf.keras.layers` as well as `tf.python.keras.layers`. The difference is, that autocorrect works just in the latter case correctly. It seems to be a common issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m49LAkcij0c Thank you for the link to the topic about `tf.python`.

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to thushv89 and some additional research I found some kind of explanation and solution:

https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server/issues/818

The way TensorFlow handels imports cannot be read by VS Code easily. Using `tf.python.keras` is a work around, but definitely not recommended. Other ways to solve this issue are described here:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32982

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved when using tensorflow version 2.2.