# Unexpected performance differences between keras and tensorflow.keras in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am building a model in python based on a simple autoencoder example that I found online. The example was written for keras. With the recommended transition to tensorflow.keras I modified the program's imports expecting no other changes would be needed.

With the keras imports

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
from keras.datasets import mnist
```

the autoencoder works fine, you can see it converge in the std output, and the recovered images make sense. When I use the tensorflow inputs

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.python.keras.datasets import mnist
```

the results no longer converge and the recovered images just look like noise.

Below is the minimum working example of my problem. Just change between the two imports above to reproduce the difference in behavior.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def prepModel(inputShape, outputShape, numNeurons):
    input_image = Input(shape=(inputShape,))

    #encoded representation of input
    encoded = Dense(numNeurons, activation='relu')(input_image)
    #decoded lossy reconstruction
    decoded = Dense(outputShape, activation='sigmoid')(encoded)

    #model to encoded data
    autoencoder = Model(input_image, decoded)

    encoder = Model(input_image, encoded)
    encoded_input = Input(shape=(numNeurons,)) #placeholder
    decoder_layer = autoencoder.layers[-1] #last layer of model
    decoder = Model(encoded_input, decoder_layer(encoded_input)) #decoder model

    autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')

    return autoencoder, encoder, decoder


def prepData():
    #import / set data
    (x_train, _), (x_test, _) = mnist.load_data()
    x_train = x_train.astype('float32')/255
    x_test = x_test.astype('float32')/255

    x_train = x_train.reshape((len(x_train), np.prod(x_train.shape[1:])))
    x_test = x_test.reshape((len(x_test), np.prod(x_test.shape[1:])))

    return x_train, x_test


def runModel(autoencoder, encoder, decoder, x_train, x_test):
    #train encoder
    autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train,
                    epochs=50,
                    batch_size=256,
                    shuffle=True,
                    validation_data=(x_test, x_test))

    encoded_images = encoder.predict(x_test)
    decoded_images = decoder.predict(encoded_images)

    return encoded_images, decoded_images


def plotComparison(x_test, decoded_images):
    #Plot original image
    n = 10
    plt.figure(figsize=(20,4))
    for i in range(n):
        ax = plt.subplot(2,n,i+1)
        plt.imshow(x_test[i].reshape(28,28))
        plt.gray()
        ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
        ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
     #plot decompressed image
        ax = plt.subplot(2, n, i+1+n)
        plt.imshow(decoded_images[i].reshape(28,28))
        plt.gray()
        ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
        ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
    plt.show()


x_train, x_test = prepData()
autoencoder, encoder, decoder = prepModel(784, 784, 16)
encoded_images, decoded_images = runModel(autoencoder, encoder, decoder, x_train, x_test)
plotComparison(x_test, decoded_images)
```

I'm running python 3.8.3, keras version 2.3.1, and tensorflow version 2.2.0. I've fooled around with rescaling the input data and other naive tricks to no avail. And I've verified the behavior on two other computers. What could explain why the performance between the two sets of imports is so different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is because of `optimizer='adadelta'`. As described [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/39432#issuecomment-627215010):

> **the default learning rate for Adadelta optimizer in keras version is
>   1.0 and in tensorflow.keras is 0.001.**

So to fix the problem try to use `optimizer = tensorflow.keras.optimizers.Adadelta(lr = 1.0)` instead of `optimizer='adadelta'`. Or alternatively you can use another optimizer, like 'adam'.

**Additinal note:** Also as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58279629/6396770) try to use `tensorflow.keras.*` instead of `tensorflow.python.keras.*`.

> Importing from tensorflow.python or any other modules (including
>   import tensorflow_core) is not supported, and can break unannounced.